# "can do better than V" and "can do worse than V"

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs, idioms-in-context

"Can do worse than V" (as a way to make a suggestion) is much less common than "could do worse than V."

For example, "could" is used by more people than "can" in:

> He can/could do worse than marry Sarah.

What about "can do better than V"? For those who say "could do worse than V" as opposed to "can do worse than V," would you say "can do better than V" or "could do better than V"?

Comment: Google books suggests “can do better than” https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+do+better+than%2C+could+do+better+than%2C+could+do+worse+than%2C+can+do+worse+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20do%20better%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20do%20better%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20do%20worse%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20do%20worse%20than%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ngrams tells you what is used more often. It doesn’t tell you what’s right in a specific situation. Take affect and effect. You don’t use what ngram says is used more often, you use what’s right.

Comment: @user070221: That's a misleading NGram link. ***Can*** is much more common in general, but ***not*** if the [hypothetical] "not worst" option is [***could** do worse than **marry**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+do+better+than+marry%2Ccould+do+better+than+marry%2Ccould+do+worse+than+marry%2Ccan+do+worse+than+marry&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20do%20better%20than%20marry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20do%20better%20than%20marry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20do%20worse%20than%20marry%3B%2Cc0) [someone]*.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of likelihood. If Joe and Sarah are at the altar and you think he makes a mistake you say “he could do better than marry her” - could because there is a 99% chance he will marry her. But if Joe is looking for a wife and had a first date that didn’t go well, Joe will say “I can do better than marry Sarah” because it’s very unlikely he would.

On the other hand, if the date went well he’d say “I could do worse than marry her” because he doesn’t want to do worse obviously. “I can do worse” doesn’t make sense because he has no intention of doing worse.

Rule: You don’t care what’s used more often. You use what’s right.

Comment: Does the "can" in "I can do better than marry Sarah" refer to ability?